# who can use instant token?

Tags: box-api

I am interested in using box instant tokens. The documentation says it is in "private beta". What does private beta mean and who can participate in private beta?

Also, what do I need to do enable my app to make /tokens endpoint call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private beta == contact us at apiATbox[dot]com if you have a good use case so that we can enable it for your API key. We're still working through some of the edge cases and are working closely with the developers in the beta to resolve them.